# Looking for an example or draft of an IP-related agreement for industry employment

Tags: industry, legal-issues, intellectual-property, contract

Researchers which start doing industrial work while continuing independent research are in a delicate position with respect to the part of their contract/employment agreement governing "intellectual property", confidential employer-owned information and the like. Often, commercial companies are only used to industry-experience-only hires, and have thus gotten away with agreements saying basically "we own everything you do or will do (or have done) that is related to company business", essentially preventing the employee from ever doing independent research in the field, contributing to FOSS etc.

What I'm looking for here is an example agreement, or part of an agreement, which is reasonably drafted to be fair to the researcher-employee. Something actually used in real life would be great (no need for identifying personal details of course).

Comment: I wonder if an agreement between a company and a research group, where the research group acts as a subcontractor to the company on a research project, would also be helpful?

Comment: @MadJack: Probably, and - it definitely can't hurt to look at one of those...